# Why Tkinter place_forget() is not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

For some reason when I try to use place_forget() or grid_forget() they won't work
My code

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Chat test")

startframe = tk.Frame(root)
buttonstart = tk.Button(startframe)
newframe = tk.Frame(root)
newbutton = tk.Button(newframe)

def drawStart():
    startframe = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue", width=1100, height=600)
    startframe.grid()
    buttonstart = tk.Button(startframe, command=start, text="button")
    buttonstart.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="s")

def start():
    buttonstart.place_forget()
    startframe.grid_forget()
    newframe = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue", width=1100, height=600)
    newframe.grid()
    newbutton = tk.Button(startframe, command=start, text="button")
    newbutton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="s")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    drawStart()
    root.mainloop()
```

Instead they remain and new frame is created below the current one. I'm using the latest version of Python.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3bm4.png)

Comment: As a general rule, it's better to `configure` the controls you have rather than destroy and create.

Comment: Your problem is that the "buttonstart" and "startframe" in `drawStart` are local to that function.  They are not related to the globals.  After creating those globals. you don't really need to create them again in your function.  I suggest you remove those first four definitions, and add a `global` declaration for the values you are creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the "buttonstart" and "startframe" in `drawStart` are local to that function. They are not related to the globals. After creating those globals. you don't really need to create them again in your function. I suggest you remove those first four definitions, and add a `global` declaration for the values you are creating.

This does what you expect.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Chat test")

def drawStart():
    global startframe
    global buttonstart
    startframe = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue", width=1100, height=600)
    startframe.grid()
    buttonstart = tk.Button(startframe, command=start, text="button")
    buttonstart.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="s")

def start():
    global newframe
    global newbutton
    buttonstart.place_forget()
    startframe.grid_forget()
    newframe = tk.Frame(root, bg="blue", width=1100, height=600)
    newframe.grid()
    newbutton = tk.Button(startframe, command=start, text="button")
    newbutton.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="s")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    drawStart()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really works for me. 
On a side note. Could you point me to a place with fresh tkinter documentations? All I can find is outdated. Again, thanks.

Comment: Tkinter IS outdated.    It is an awful library, and encourages poor programming practices.  It was thrown into Python 1 because there were no viable alternatives in the early 1990s.  When you start tkinter, that launches a second interpreter for a completely different language (tcl), which is in itself a terrible language, and every API call gets converted to a tcl command to that interpreter.  If you really want to do Python GUIs, please go look at a real choice, like Qt or wxWidgets.

Comment: @TimRoberts PyQt looked slower than tkinter in my hands (could be I wasnt using it properly ) but ... Any thought on that ?

Comment: How do you define "slower" for a UI framework?  UI frameworks are almost never CPU-bound.  They are user-action-bound.

Comment: @TimRoberts: This answer is just a block of code; it would be much better if it had an explanation on what was changed, and why. Even if that information is in your comments, it's worth writing a good answer, and not that much effort.